# Iterating over very large JSON array

Tags: json, loops, large-data

I have a 7000+ object JSON array that I would like to present as a list with live search and two-way sorting.

I've been looking at Angular, and have successfully made a list with live search, but it's obviously very slow with all this data.

What would be the most optimal way to handle this? Are there other libraries out there, that could handle the job better?

Comment: What is slow? Parsing it (if it's actually JSON)? Creating a DOM representation of it? Searching and sorting it?

Comment: Loading, search and sorting is kinda slow, as the browser has to "download" all the data, before it can be manipulated in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use streaming api for JSON parsing? Check 3 ways [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Comment: But eventually to search and sort you're going to have to hold the whole thing in memory.